# Delete comment from database php

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I am trying to delete comments from my comment system but the code I have is not working. I want to be able to delete each comment from my table including the parent comments. At the moment my code does not get the parameter of the comment from the delete button link.

`function.php`:

```
<?php
function getComments($row) {
    echo "<li class='comment'>";
    echo "<div class='aut'>" . $row['author'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div class='comment-body'>" . $row['comment'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div class='timestamp'>" . $row['created_at'] . "</div>";
    echo "<a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit Song</a>"; 
    echo "<span> </span>";
    echo "<a href='delete.php?id='" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete Song</a>"; 
    $q = "SELECT * FROM threaded_comments WHERE parent_id = ".$row['id']."";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if(mysql_num_rows($r)>0)
        {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
            getComments($row);
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        }
    echo "</li>";
}
?>
```

`delete.php`:

```
<?php 
    include 'includes/config.php';

    $deleteid = $_GET['id'];

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM threaded_comments WHERE id='$deleteid'");

    echo "Song has been deleted!";
    header ('Location: index.php');
?>
```

I have added the index.php and post_comment page page. Also the delete function still doesn't work when I made the changes.

`index.php`:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
include("functions.php");
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Multi-Lyric Collaboration System</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.pack.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $("a.reply").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#parent_id").attr("value", id);
        $("#name").focus();
    });
});
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, p, blockquote,
pre, form, fieldset, table, th, td { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {
font-size: 14px;
line-height:1.3em;
background: url('music.jpg');
height: 100%;
background-size:100% ;
background-position: static;
background-color: purple;
min-height: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
label{
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}

a, a:visited {
outline:none;
color:#7d5f1e;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}

#wrapper {
    width:480px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:15px 0px;
}

.comment {
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top:15px;
    list-style:none;
    background-color: white;
      opacity: 0.96;
        -moz-border-radius:20px;
  -webkit-border-radius:20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}

.aut {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.timestamp {
    font-size:85%;
    float:right;
}

#comment_form {
    margin-top:15px;

}

#comment_form input {
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin:0 0 10px;
    padding:3px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;

}

#comment_body {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;

}

#submit_button {
    text-align:center; 
    clear:both;
}
header{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='wrapper'>
    <header><font size="20">MultiLyric Collaborator</font></header>
    <br>
<ul>
<?php
$q = "SELECT * FROM threaded_comments WHERE parent_id = 0";
$r = mysql_query($q);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):
    getComments($row);
endwhile;
?>
</ul>

    <form id="comment_form" action="post_comment.php" method='post'>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id='name'/>

    <label for="comment_body">Enter Song:</label>
    <textarea name="comment_body" id='comment_body'></textarea>
    <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='0'/>
    <div id='submit_button'>
        <input type="submit" value="Add comment"/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`post_comment.php`:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$comment_body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment_body']);
$parent_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parent_id']);
$q = "INSERT INTO threaded_comments (author, comment, parent_id) VALUES ('$author', '$comment_body', $parent_id)";
$r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()==1) {
    header("location:index.php");
}
else {
    echo "Comment cannot be posted. Please try again.";
}
?>
```

Comment: In what way does this not work?  What is the link created by the first part of the code?  What is the SQL query created by the second part of the code?  Also note that your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  You're going to want to use prepared statements with query parameters, rather than just blindly executing user input as code.

Comment: This code also moves the user around, which is not necessary with some basic javascript

Answer (score 0):

From the "SELECT" statement in getComments(), it looks like what you need to do is:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM threaded_comments WHERE parent_id ='$deleteid'");
```

It is 'parent_id' not 'id'.